# How to get n rows to combine to one, and show other rows unchanged

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this `table`

```
Col1        Col2
--------------------
1           100
2           50
3           60
4           70
5           20
```

---

I am trying to add multiple rows into one row with total
For example if input is `2`, result is a row that has sum of `row1` to `row2`,and `row3` to end row.

Here is what I want as results for my mock data:

```
Col1        Col2
--------------------
1           150(sum(row1 and row2)
2            60
3            70
4            20
```

Comment: Are the values in `Col1` in the input table always one-based and dense, i.e. start at `1` and have no missing (or duplicated) values? If not it complicates things a bit since the first _n_ values to be summed may not be `Col1` 1 through _n_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can `GROUP BY` with `CASE` and then add the row numbers with `RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1), 
  col2 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      CASE WHEN col1 <= 2 THEN 0 ELSE col1 END col1, 
      SUM([Col2]) col2 
    FROM 
      some_table 
    GROUP BY 
      CASE WHEN col1 <= 2 THEN 0 ELSE col1 END
  ) a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(col1), sum(col2) from table
where col1 is <= 2
UNION
select col1, col2 from table
where col1 is > 2
```

Note here though that col1 is not changed for rows 2 onwards.